# Do not stop a storyboard when VisualState ends

Tags: wpf, xaml

We have a custom ImageButton where we show a different image while button is pressed.  We have requirement to have button stay active for 1 second regardless of whether the user click/touches the button that long.  I am finding that the storyboard stops when the user releases the click or touch.  Is there a way to NOT stop the storyboard and keep it executing? Tried to specify a duration of a little over a second but didn't help.  Here is relevant code:

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled="False" Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled="False">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                      <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                          <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <Storyboard x:Name="VisualStatePressedStoryboard" Duration="0:0:1.1" >
                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PressedImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                          </VisualState>
                      </VisualStateGroup>
              </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

 <Image Name="DefaultImage" Source="{TemplateBinding DefaultImageSource}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stretch="Fill" >
  </Image>
  <Image Name="PressedImage" Source="{TemplateBinding PressedImageSource}" Stretch="Fill" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Visibility="Hidden" />
  </Grid>
```

I also tried a lot of other things with Trigger for IsPressed property, EventTrigger for TouchDown event, etc...

thanks,

Comment: I guess this may not be possible... as per MSDN "When the control exits the state, the Storyboard stops."  https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.microsoft.com%2Fwinfx%2F2006%2Fxaml%2Fpresentation%23VisualState);k(http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.microsoft.com%2Fwinfx%2F2006%2Fxaml%2Fpresentation%23VisualStateGroup);k(vs.xmleditor);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1)&rd=true

Answer (score 0):

I did it with the EnterActions of a data trigger, and not specifying an exit action:

```
<Trigger Property="IsPressedValue="True"> 
  <Trigger.EnterActions> 
    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowPressedImageStoryboard}" x:Name="IsPressedEnterActionsStoryboard" /> 
   </Trigger.EnterActions>
</Trigger>
```